# Regular expression restrictions

Tags: html, regex

I am new to regular expressions. I have a text field and I need to limit the input to numbers and one comma. I know how to limit to numbers. But I have another condition. If the user enters a comma, they must enter another number after that. There is no restriction on the number of digits. There can only be one comma. The following are all valid inputs:
123456
4567,8907

but I can't allow 4567,.
I have this pattern, pattern="[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?"
 but it's not working.

Comment: `pattern="[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?"` is a good pattern for that. It works on submit, not when the user types.

Comment: Allow optional whitespace after the comma?

Comment: Your pattern looks good to me but can be shortened. See https://regex101.com/r/OvZNyM/2 - what value is it not working for?

Comment: Is `123456` valid? What about `,123456`? What about `123456,`?

Comment: is nothing valid? also I interpreted it as 123456 is allowed

Comment: On clicking submit, it allowed me to save the following value: <input type="text" class="form-control"  pattern="[0-9]+([\,][0-9]+)?" id="userId" name="userId" value="qaz mnnn"/> 123456 is valid too. 123456,789 is valid as well. But 1234, is not.

Comment: Is `,123456` valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex allows any number of digits (including none), followed optionally by a single comma, followed by any number of digits. This pattern must span from beginning to end using the `^` and `$` symbols, so no other characters are allowed:

```
^[0-9]*,?[0-9]+$
```

Try here:

```js
let inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
let p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
inp.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let result = inp.value.match(`^[0-9]*,?[0-9]+$`);
  p.innerHTML = `Is "${inp.value}" allowed? ${result ? 'YES' : 'NO'}`;
});
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="try a value here"/>
<p></p>
```

Comment: I tried your code. I entered 1234. It says not allowed.

Comment: use ^[0-9]*(,[0-9]+)*$  That is, group the second part, and it will satisfy the requirements.

Comment: @G.Swa I'm wasn't sure if, where the question says "There can only be one comma", this refers to exactly one comma, or "one or zero commas". See the edit!

Comment: This is almost working. But it's allowing me to save 123,456,789. There should only be one comma. The group should be allowed only once.

Comment: `123,456,789` (and any string with more than 1 comma) fails this regex